# MySQL query sorting/grouping performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, sorting, group-by

I have a table 'content' with the following fields:

```
id (an unique, increasing identifier)
user_id
content1
content2
content3
...
```

The table can contain data from the same or different `user_id`. I am trying to select data sorted by one of the `content` fields. However I only want to select data from distinct 'user_id' and always take the user's latest entry (so the highest `id` value). I cannot simply `group by user_id` because grouping happens before sorting.

This is what I am doing at the moment:

```
SELECT *
FROM `content`
WHERE `content`.`id` = (
    SELECT `id`
    FROM `content` as `alt`
    WHERE `alt`.`user_id` = `content`.`id`
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT 1 )
ORDER BY content1 DESC
```

It works but once the table gets bigger, the performance becomes too slow.
Can someone give me an advice how to improve this query?

Comment: What are the indexes on the table?

Comment: This is explained in the mysql manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it's slow with more data is because your subquery is executing for ***each row*** in the `content` table.

This solution should be much quicker as the subselect will only execute once, where the result of that subselect is then *joined* to the same table - utlizing indexes:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid
    FROM content
    GROUP BY user_id
) a
INNER JOIN content b ON a.maxid = b.id
ORDER BY b.content1 DESC
```

Comment: @user1509487, great! If you found this answer to be useful, please mark it as "accepted". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you needs 2 step approach not 1 complete SQL for performance.

1. create temporary table

   create temporary table id_Temp as
   SELECT `id`
   FROM `content` as `alt`
   WHERE `alt`.`user_id` = `content`.`id`
2. select data from temporary table

   SELECT *
   FROM `content`
   WHERE `content`.`id` = ( select id from id_temp ORDER BY `id` DESC limit 1)
   ORDER BY content1 DESC

in my experience, this 2 step approach make constant response time.
with this approach, 2.5 mil pages/day web site works well with cheap 2 Liunx BOX.